# Ant task : how to create Base 64 images

Tags: css, ant, base64

I'm creating an offline version of my website. To do it, I want to build the whole site into a single html file. The last step consists of converting all the images of my CSS to Base64 using ANT.

I've tried to use a tool called Jawr, but I get a "null pointer" exception... And I really don't know why: I've tried then with a very short css file, but it doesn't work either...

Any idea?

Comment: Online convert image to Base64: http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Comment: Here's another one: http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/        Also, in future, avoid writing `I can't make it work` in your questions without any more information. It makes it very frustrating for anyone who's trying to help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to create a zip or tar archive of your site?

Comment: @Mark: it's simpler indeed but if I can have just one file, I would prefer that ^^ ... That's why I'm trying to do that, but if I can't, I'm gonna do an archive.

Comment: @Robbie: Thanks for the links, but that's not really what I've asked...

Comment: @Nicolas Then what are you trying to do? Also, if you're trying to have all your files in one document, take a look at [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML).

Comment: actually, I thought that "build" was clear... Be indeed it's not ^^ ... I want to automatize it (with Ant for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a way:

To do it, I've used an 'exec' task which call a php script. In this script, I call php's base64_encode function.

For more details about including base64 converted images to your CSS using PHP, see http://devin.la/blog/base64-encode-images-css-script-mobile.

Finally, to wait until my new CSS file is ready, I use the 'waitfor' ant task.